# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'checked': object is null or undefined only in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, runtime-error

I have to check items in check box and then click add button which will add the checked items to a box. after checking the items in check box and while clicking add button i get below error.It occurs only in IE9.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'checked': object is null or undefined

My js page code is:

```
document.onkeyup = fnRemoveSelectedItems;
//Global variables 
var cssGridrow="gridrow";
var cssGridalteraterow="gridalteraterow";
var selectedItems=new String();
var pickItemSelected="1";
var isOnsiteLoc = 0;

/*Function that adds the selected items to the text box in the pick up box */
function fnPickUpAdd(btnOKClientId, lstFromClientId, txtBoxClientId, ColumnToTake) {
    //enable the ok button
    document.getElementById(btnOKClientId).disabled=false;
    //From grid Object
    var lstFrom=document.getElementById(lstFromClientId);
    //to textbox Object
    var txtBoxObject=document.getElementById(txtBoxClientId);

    //If the lstFromClienId is location then iteration occurs.
    if (lstFromClientId.search(/Location/i) > 0) {
        //Iterating only with in the grid rows to check if the location is onsite
        for (var i = 1; i < lstFrom.rows.length; i++) {
            var CheckBoxId = lstFrom.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].id;
            if (document.getElementById(CheckBoxId).checked && lstFrom.rows[i].cells[6].innerText != null && lstFrom.rows[i].cells[6].innerText == "True") {
                isOnsiteLoc = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Iterating only with in the grid rows to get the selected SOIDs
    for(var i=0;i<lstFrom.rows.length; i++) {
        if(lstFrom.rows[i].className==cssGridrow || lstFrom.rows[i].className==cssGridalteraterow) {
            var childRowCheckBoxId=lstFrom.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].id;
            if(childRowCheckBoxId!= "") {
                if(document.getElementById(childRowCheckBoxId).checked) {
                    //locationmatchFor = "1" for all scenarios except for location pick up in search
                    // so for this we would take the value in cells[1]
                    if(ColumnToTake=='1'){ //From Preferences 
                        if(findMatchValue(txtBoxObject, lstFrom.rows[i].cells[1].innerText)==false) {
                            //show that in the text box
                            txtBoxObject.innerHTML+="<span onclick='fnSelectItem(this)' isItem=1>"+lstFrom.rows[i].cells[1].innerText+";</span>";

                            //Form this to pass the selected items to the parent page
                            //selectedItems+=(lstFrom.rows[i].cells[1].innerText)+":"+(lstFrom.rows[i].cells[2].innerText);
                            selectedItems+=(lstFrom.rows[i].cells[1].innerText);
                            selectedItems+=";";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line in that wall of code does the error occur on? What you you looked at to figure out the problem? (I mean, fairly obviously the `id` you're looking up in one of your `getElementById` calls isn't valid.) What do you see when you step through with the debugger built into the browser?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with html and events which act on this script.

Comment: `console.log(lstFrom.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].nodeType)` before you try to get the `id`. `nodeType` should be `1`, not `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is no `DOM` property `id` that you trying to access in the following lines:

```
var CheckBoxId = lstFrom.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].id;
```

and

```
var childRowCheckBoxId=lstFrom.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].id;
```

Is `id` an attribute? If so, you can try doing

```
getAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following the head of your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that in your `For` loop you are looping past the last row of the grid.  Check the `Length` property and see if it includes the "page number row" in the count.  `i < Length - 1` worked for me.